# Finding Coordinates on a 3D vector

Tags: geometry

My question is how to find the coordinates for a point on segment $KL$ where 
$K=(3,2,1)$ and $L=(7,9,5)$ that is $5$ units away from $K$.

I know that the vector is $KL=[4,7,4]$ and the length of the entire vector is $9$ but not sure how to move the point along the vector by $5$ units

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: any point P *between* $K$ and $L$ is of the form:
$$P = K + \lambda \left( L-K \right)$$
for some $0 \le \lambda \le 1$. Find $\lambda$ such that $d(P,K) = 5$.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

We want to move $\dfrac 59$ of the vector $[4,7,4]$, which is $\left[2\frac29, 3\frac89,2\frac29\right]$

This equates to the point

\begin{align}P&=K+\frac 59(KL)\\
&=(3,2,1)+\frac59[4,7,4]\\
&=(3,2,1)+\left[2\frac29, 3\frac89,2\frac29\right]\\
&=\left(5\frac 29,5\frac89,3\frac29\right)\\
&\approx (5.22, 5.89, 3.22)\quad(2\text{d.p.})\end{align}